# How do I actually get the output of kubectl kustomize into my cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, k3s, kustomize

I have a very simple kustomization.yaml:

```
configMapGenerator:
  - name: icecast-conifg
    files:
      - icecast.xml
```

When I run `kubectl kustomize .` it spits out a generated configMap properly, but how do I actually load it into my cluster?   I'm missing some fundamental step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Kustomize you can use the `-k` (or `--kustomize`) flag instead of `-f` when using `kubectl apply`. Example:

```
kubectl apply -k <my-folder-or-file>
```

See [Declarative Management of Kubernetes Objects Using Kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/)

Comment: do you happen to know if Argo will automatically apply kustomization.yaml?

Comment: I don't know. But if it checks out from Git it probably works as you do locally if every file is committed to Git.

Answer (score 2):

You could do for example

```
kubectl kustomize . | kubectl apply -f -
```